# Alternatives to Base64 encoding with WebSockets

Tags: encoding, websocket, base64

What are the alternatives for the encoding of binary data that can be used with WebSockets? I only know that you can use Base64. Are there others?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Encoding of binary data as text is rarely necessary anymore since basically all browsers with WebSocket support now support sending/received raw binary data via Typed Arrays (arraybuffers) and Blobs. There are only a few occasions where this is necessary:

- Using the [web-socket-js](https://github.com/gimite/web-socket-js) fallback with browsers that don't have WebSocket support builtin such as Internet Explorer 6-9 and firefox 3.6. Note that the reason that web-socket-js does not support binary data is because these browsers do not support Typed Arrays and Blobs so "binary" data already would be encoded somehow in the browser (often as normal arrays of numbers from 0-255) or as strings with non-ASCII character values.
- On browsers that only support the WebSocket Hixie protocol (which did not have the ability to send raw binary data) such as Safari (mobile and desktop) versions less than 6.

In those situations, base64 is not your only encoding option. Any encoding that results in valid UTF-8 text (the text format support by all versions of WebSockets) will work. Base64 just happens to be very easy to support in the browser via the atob and btoa functions. For example, if you have an array of numbers that represent binary byte values, then you could just encode this to a JSON string which is safe to send via any WebSocket version:

```
JSON.stringify([120,32,255])
'[120,32,255]'
```

It is simple and human readable, but it's quite a bit less space efficient than base64. There are also more efficient ways of encoding binary data to UTF-8 strings that would be much more space efficient, however, they would end up consuming a more CPU resources in the browser and require a custom algorithm to map the binary data to UTF-8 code points.

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate answer.

Answer (score 2):

WebSockets support raw binary data. How this is exposed depends on what language/library/API you are using. In JavaScript/browsers you can call send with Typed arrays (ArrayBuffer or Blob). When receiving a binary message it will be delivered as one of those types. The WebSocket browser API documentation (http://www.w3.org/TR/websockets/) has more information about how this is done.